# How to create a new line for command prompt?

Tags: command-prompt

After one command has been initiated, I want to insert another line

I vaguely remember something about pressing the <kbd>Q</kbd> button or <kbd>F</kbd> button for something but can't seem to get it correct. (<kbd>Enter</kbd> doesn't work)

Like after that last line in after 1081 modules, how can I get another command in?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Don't understand your question properly. But if you are using vim. Press "i" to insert any character or newline.